# How to use upsert() to insert/update a database table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-9

I got Array to String conversion error each time i tried using UPSERT() to update a table in Laravel-9

What i tried:

View page:

```
<tr id="me"'+newid+' class="rowca"><td>'+newid+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+v.studs_id+'<input type="hidden" name="studs_id[]" style="width:100px"         value="'+v.studs_id+'"><input type="hidden" name="studcaID[]" style="width:100px"   value="'+v.studcaID+'"></td>'+
    '<td>'+v.student.surName+' '+v.student.firstName+' '+v.student.otherName+'</td>'+
    '<td><input type="number" name="ca1[]" class="entry" style="width:40px" value="'+v.ca1+'"></td>'+
    '<td><input type="number" name="ca2[]" class="entry" style="width:40px" value="'+v.ca2+'"> </td>'+
    '<td><input type="number" name="ca3[]" class="entry" style="width:40px" value="'+v.ca3+'"></td>'+
    '<td><input type="number" name="exam[]" class="entry" style="width:40px" value="'+v.exam+'"></td>'+
    '<td><input type="number" name="e_exam[]" class="entry" style="width:40px" value="'+v.e_exam+'" readonly></td>'+
    '<td><input type="text" name="total[]" class="total" style="width:50px" value="'+v.total+'" readonly></td>'+
    '<td><input type="text" name="grade[]" class="grade" style="width:40px" value="'+v.grade+'" readonly></td>'+
    '<td><input type="hidden" name="remarkID[]" class="remark" style="width:100px" value="'+v.remarkID+'" readonly ></td>'+
    '</tr>
```

My Controller:

```
public function MarksEntryUpdate(Request $request)
       {
        $data[] = [
            'ca1'=>$request->ca1,
            'ca2'=>$request->ca2,
            'ca3'=>$request->ca3,
            'exam'=>$request->exam,
            'total'=>$request->total,
            'grade'=>$request->grade,
            'remarkID'=>$request->remarkID,
        ];

        TerminalAssessment::upsert($data, ['studcaID'], ['ca1', 'ca2']);

        $notification = array(
            'message' => 'Class Assessment Successfully Updated...!',
            'alert-type' => 'success'
        );

        return redirect()->route('marks_entry.add')->with($notification);
      }
```

Comment: Please can anyone help me out. I need this code to work please.

Comment: @Wahyu Kristianto thanks for helping me editing my post.

Comment: you are passing an array of non-associative arrays

Comment: Please how best should i go about it.

Comment: I'm trying to answer this. Check my answer. Let me know if it not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an array of associative arrays instead of an array of non-associative arrays

```php
public function MarksEntryUpdate(Request $request)
{
    $data = [];

    // Loop over the values in each row and create an associative array for each row
    foreach ($request->studs_id as $key => $value) {
        $data[] = [
            'studcaID' => $request->studcaID[$key],
            'ca1' => $request->ca1[$key],
            'ca2' => $request->ca2[$key],
            'ca3' => $request->ca3[$key],
            'exam' => $request->exam[$key],
            'total' => $request->total[$key],
            'grade' => $request->grade[$key],
            'remarkID' => $request->remarkID[$key],
        ];
    }

    TerminalAssessment::upsert($data, ['studcaID'], ['ca1', 'ca2']);

    $notification = array(
        'message' => 'Class Assessment Successfully Updated...!',
        'alert-type' => 'success'
    );

    return redirect()->route('marks_entry.add')->with($notification);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Wahyu Kristianto. Your answer has solved my problem.